# Bootstrap one carousel with two carousel-indicators

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically what I am trying to do is, I have one Bootstrap carousel with 8 slides in it.I am using 2 carousel-indicators.

This is my first indicator it work fine with `.active` class

```
<ol class="rightci carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" ></li>
</ol>
```

this is my Second Indicator it works fine.when I click on the link carousel slides change perfectly but `.active` class dose not change automatically rather on first indicators `.active` changes fine.

```
<div class="left leftci carousel-indicators">
<a href=""><span class="leftindicators active" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0">slide1</span></a>
</div>
```

help me with it

Comment: you have 8 slides and only 2 indicators. can you clearly explain what is your issue?

Comment: the first Indicator work fine with `.active` class. For example when #first slide slides to #second slide, and as on.... `active' class of first indicator changes with it... Problem is with second indicator..... it dosen't changes as per the slides

Comment: indicator has `active` class when its image is active! you need 8 indicators and valid bootstrap's markup for them

Comment: yes what i want to do is use 8X8 i.e. two separate indicators list...is there any way to do this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/a74hsven/  I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thakyou Lvancha But what I want is https://jsfiddle.net/ppwn8oau/    As You see one indicator dosenot change active class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to write some custom js Bootstrap has not this functionality by default so you need to make your own `carousel-indicators`

css

```
.carousel-indicators2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -30%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.carousel-indicators2 li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000\9;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.carousel-indicators2 .active {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

JS

```
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  $(".carousel-indicators2 li").removeClass("active");
  indicators = $(".carousel-indicators li.active").data("slide-to");
  a = $(".carousel-indicators2").find("[data-slide-to='" + indicators + "']").addClass("active");
  console.log(indicators);

})
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyvogww5/)**

Answer (score 2):

I too faced similar kind of issue. So I too used above given solution. But was not working correctly on click. 
So here is what I did to fix this issue 100%. With little enhancement on above solution.

**Issue:** I wanted to show 2 indicators for one carousel. Everything works fine after using above solution but fails after clicking.

**Solution:** So I tried this

```
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  var indicatorsAct = $(".carousel-indicator-icons li.active").data("slide-to");
  $(".carousel-indicators-numbers li").removeClass("active");
  $(".carousel-indicators-numbers").find("[data-slide-to='" + indicatorsAct + "']")
    .addClass("active");
});

$('ol.carousel-indicator-icons li').on("click",function(){ 
  $('ol.carousel-indicator-icons li.active').removeClass("active");
  $("ol.carousel-indicators-numbers li.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");   
  var indicators = $(this).data("slide-to");
  $(".carousel-indicators-numbers").find("[data-slide-to='" + indicators + "']")
    .addClass("active");
});
```

Where `.carousel-indicator-icons` is the container class for first indicator and `.carousel-indicators-numbers` is the class for second indicator.

*I hope this will help to other folks who faced similar issue.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution without using JQuery.

I gave the second indicator bar the ID #custom-carousel-indicators.

```
let carouselIndicatorButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#custom-carousel-indicators button')
document.querySelectorAll('.carousel').forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
        let activeIndicator = document.querySelector('.carousel-indicators button.active')

        carouselIndicatorButtons.forEach((button2) => {
            button2.classList.remove('active')
        })

        document.querySelector('#custom-carousel-indicators button[data-bs-slide-to="'
            + activeIndicator.dataset.bsSlideTo + '"]').classList.add('active')
    });
});
```