# Bootstrap Carousal need two pagination dots with active class on both

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

i need your help to solve a issue with bootstrap caraousal pagination. actually, i need two pagination dots on a carousal slider. One will be at bottom of top and one will be in right-side. and both have active class like it show current slide image number. For more check image below you will understand batter. 
[here is image that help you to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKBRV.jpg)

here is code i'm using may it can help you also
Fisrt one pagination

```
 <ol class="carousel-indicators ">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">Icon details</li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">Icon details</li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">Icon details here</li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3">Icon details here</li>
          </ol>
```

Second Right Side Pagination code

```
<div class="carouselrightside">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel"  data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
```

this one is middle image code

```
<div class="carousel-inner"><div class="recursos_wrap center item active"> <img class="" src="images/recursos1.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div><div class="recursos_wrap center item "> <img class="" src="images/recursos2.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div><div class="recursos_wrap center item "> <img class="" src="images/recursos3.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div><div class="recursos_wrap center item "> <img class="" src="images/recursos4.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div></div>
```

that's all please help thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you add your javascript code?

Comment: there is no javascript code i'm using bootstrap carasoual slider with pagination simply

Comment: Can you add your css ?

Comment: css for which one rightside pagination or leftside?

Comment: @BharathShetty  any help?

Comment: This might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651276/bootstrap-one-carousel-with-two-carousel-indicators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add and remove **active** class to second carousel indicators using js

```js
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  $(".carouselrightside .carousel-indicators li").removeClass("active");
  indicators = $(".carousel-indicators li.active").data("slide-to");
  a = $(".carouselrightside .carousel-indicators").find("[data-slide-to='" + indicators + "']").addClass("active");
})
```

```css
 .carousel-inner>.item{
   background-color: pink;
   min-width: 300px;
   min-height: 300px;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide myCarousel" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators ">
      <li data-target=".myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">Icon details</li>
      <li data-target=".myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">Icon details</li>
      <li data-target=".myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">Icon details here</li>
      <li data-target=".myCarousel" data-slide-to="3">Icon details here</li>
    </ol>


    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->    
<div class="carousel-inner"><div class="recursos_wrap center item active"> <img class="" src="images/recursos1.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div><div class="recursos_wrap center item "> <img class="" src="images/recursos2.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div><div class="recursos_wrap center item "> <img class="" src="images/recursos3.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div><div class="recursos_wrap center item "> <img class="" src="images/recursos4.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div></div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
   <div class="carouselrightside">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="bottom: 0px;">
<li data-target=".myCarousel"  data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target=".myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target=".myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
<li data-target=".myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol></div>
  </div>
</div>
```